# Array is not a constructor in javascript unit test angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory for create dialog:

```
module myModule {
    export class myDialog {
        constructor(private $uibModal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) {}
        showDialog() {
            var options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
                templateUrl: '/dialog.html',
                size: "lg",
                controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function($scope: any, $uibModalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance) {
                    $scope.cancel = () => {
                        $uibModalInstance.close({
                            doAction: 'close'
                        });
                    }
                }],
                controllerAs: '$ctrl'
            };
            return this.$uibModal.open(options).result;
        }

        static factory(): any {
            const dialog = ($uibModal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) => new myDialog($uibModal);
            dialog.$inject = ['$uibModal'];
            return dialog;
        }
    };
    angular.module('myModule').factory('myDialog', myDialog.factory());
}
```

As you see, for `controller` injection I used array (inline array annotation) in order to work when javascript file is minified.

I created a test using bardjs:

```
describe('My dialog service', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myModule', function($provide) {
            $provide.factory('$uibModalInstance', function() {
                return {
                    close: function(result) {
                        return result;
                    }
                };
            });
        });
        module('myModule');
        bard.inject('$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance', '$http', '$httpBackend', '$q', '$rootScope', 'myDialog');
        bard.mockService($uibModal, {
            open: function(options) {
                return {
                    result: options
                };
            }
        });
        spyOn($uibModal, 'open').and.callThrough();
        spyOn($uibModalInstance, 'close').and.callThrough();
    });

    it('expect it to be defined', function() {
        expect(myDialog).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

But I got error:

> TypeError: Array is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'options.controller(scope,$uibModalInstance)')

Why ? How to solve it ?

Comment: Have you tried using `$inject` like in `dialog`?

Comment: Where and how ?

Comment: I'd try `options.controller.$inject = [/*your dependencies*/]` before passing `options` to `open` method

Comment: Typescript does not like it and won't generate `js` file ... :(

Comment: How about declaring controller before options? `const ctrl = function ...; ctrl.$inject = [/*deps*/]; var options = {... controller: ctrl, ...}`

Comment: Wonderful, it works, please post as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare controller outside `options` object and use [$inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation) to inject dependencies.

```
showDialog() {
    const ctrl = function($scope: any, $uibModalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance) {
                $scope.cancel = () => {
                    $uibModalInstance.close({
                        doAction: 'close'
                    });
                }
            };
    ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance'];

    var options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
            templateUrl: '/dialog.html',
            size: "lg",
            controller: ctrl,
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    };
    return this.$uibModal.open(options).result;
}
```